# В какой директории сохраняются модели AutoML пакета mljar-supervised?

Tags: python, automl

В описании пакета указано:
Сохранение и загрузка моделей AutoML происходит автоматически. Все модели, созданные во время обучения AutoML, сохраняются в каталоге, заданном в (аргумент конструктора). Если набора нет, то каталог создается на основе следующего соглашения об именах: будет номер от 1 до 1000 (зависит от того, какое имя каталога будет свободным).results_pathAutoML()results_pathAutoML_{number}number

Пример сохранения и загрузки:

automl = AutoML(results_path='AutoML_1');
automl.fit(X, y)

В какой директории находится этот result_path? Не смог найти.
Только начал изучать этот очень неплохой пакет.

Answer (score 0):

Все модели сохраняются в директории C:/Users/User/AutoML_n.